# Magento Shopping Cart Price Rule Disable COD Charges

Tags: magento-1.7, shopping-cart-price-rules, shopping-cart, price-rules

if a customer purchase with a specific coupon code, i wanted to disable the COD Charges

**COUPON CODE -> Applied -> Payment method -> COD : NO COD Charges ,
  COUPON CODE -> Not Applied -> Payment method -> COD : COD will be Charged ,**

How can i do this ?

Answer (score 2):

For this you can create a shoppingcart rule with the following settings:

**Rule Information:**

```
Coupon = No Coupon
```

**Conditions:**

```
Payment Method = COD
```

**Actions:**

```
Apply = Fixed Amount discount for whole cart
Discount amount = COD Charge amount
```

This will give the customer a discount that is the same as the COD Charge.

Answer (score 1):

using same conditions as suggested by Vladimir Kerkhoff, another alternative, instead of 'fixed amount for the whole cart', you can put :
Free Delivery :yes, as COD is a delivery method, it will apply free shipping.